# MYSQL - ORDER BY & LIMIT: Different result when using variable or constant

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

Query 1:

```
set @userName = 'harry';

set @previousRegionId = (
        select Region as RegionID
        from log
        where User = @userName
        order by stamp desc
        limit 1);

select @previousRegionId;
```

Query 2:

```
set @previousRegionId = (
        select Region as RegionID
        from log
        where User = 'harry'
        order by stamp desc
        limit 1);

select @previousRegionId;
```

I expect the same result for both queries, but the result is different and **it is reproduceable**!

The **log** table contains same value in **User** column for all rows ('harry').

Comment: Can you show sample output for both querys?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the order by clause. Order **by id** works "better". Order by timestamp column is suspect ...

I am not 100% sure if this approach will work in all scenarios/aspects.